# Parse float from serialized data

Tags: javascript, systems-programming

I have a buffer in NodeJS, and it received serialized data from a bluetooth device.

The serialized data is IEEE single floating-point representation, where the offset is at 21th bit.

```
accX = data.readUInt32LE(2);
accX = accX >> 4;
```

In C, I could do a memcpy to get the float number. How could I parse float in Javascript?

Comment: maybe use `Float32Array` may need to change order of the bytes first, not really sure

Comment: or better still, `DataView` and it's getFloat32 method

Answer (score 0):

**Install**

```
npm install ieee754
```

**Read the buffer**

```
var ieee754 = require('ieee754')
ieee754.read = function (buffer, offset, isLE, mLen, nBytes)
```

Reference - https://github.com/feross/ieee754